# Analysis services access through MS Excel- permissions issues

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssas

I have an instance of Analysis Services set up with my cube and am attempting to access it through MS Excel.

This works for one of my accounts but not for another. My goal is to get the second account to be able to access the cube just like the first. However, I am not sure what permissions I am missing for the second.

I have added the second user as an administrator on Analysis services and even on the SQL Server instance and yet can't get past the below error.

**How does my second account need to be set up to access the cube?**

The server name looks like: **https://[server]/OLAP/msmdpump.dll**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028837/cant-connect-to-analysis-services-via-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here was that the accounts had an Active Directory policy that was set to expire the password at first log in. In other words, the user was meant to reset their password when they first use the account.

Taking this off the password policy made the accounts work.